# ROWID as Parameters in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, rowid, ora-00904

I am trying to create a helper stored proc to save on repeated code.

I wrote the following stored procedure that takes the table name, status_id, and ROWID.

```
PROCEDURE sp_update_stage_status(p_table_name IN VARCHAR2,
                                 p_status_id IN NUMBER,
                                 p_rowid IN ROWID)
AS
BEGIN       
  execute immediate 'UPDATE ' || p_table_name
                 || ' SET STATUS_ID = ' || p_status_id 
                 || ' WHERE ROWID = ' || p_rowid;       
END;
```

However whenever I execute it I get the following.

```
ORA-00904: "AAATQEAAEAAAAHEAAB": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "OBR_DEV.PKG_COMMON", line 32
ORA-06512: at "OBR_DEV.PKG_DIRECTORY", line 449
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: To be more generic you should use data type ´UROWID`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're dropping the contents of `rowid` in directly without quoting it.

Your query became `WHERE ROWID = AAATQEAAEAAAAHEAAB` which is comparing the `rowid` column to the `AAATQEAAEAAAAHEAAB` column.
It should be `WHERE ROWID = 'AAATQEAAEAAAAHEAAB'`.  Add some quotes to your dynamic SQL and you should be okay.

Or better yet, use bind variables and don't worry about quoting:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
  'UPDATE ' || p_table_name || ' SET status_id = :status WHERE rowid = :seek_rowid'
  USING p_status_id, p_rowid;
```

Answer (score -2):

You are declaring `p_rowid` as `rowid` type, you must declare `p_rowid` as `varchar2(18)`.

```
PROCEDURE sp_update_stage_status(
   p_table_name IN VARCHAR2,
   p_status_id IN NUMBER,
   p_rowid IN VARCHAR2(18)
) AS
BEGIN
   execute immediate 'UPDATE ' || p_table_name || ' SET STATUS_ID = ' || p_status_id || ' WHERE ROWID = ' || p_rowid;
END;
```